# Pascals Triangle in Following Code Does Not Get Correct Result When Input Parameters are Big

Tags: java, overflow, pascals-triangle

A nCr problem is calculated using the following code.  For small input numbers, the results are correct.  But when n=200 and r=100, its result is 114908264. The result  should be 407336795.

What is wrong here?

```
Integer ncr(Integer n, Integer r) {
    if(n<r)
        return 0;
    long[] arr=new long[n+1];
    
    arr[0]=1l;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
            arr[j]+=arr[j-1];
        }
    }
    
    return (int)arr[r];
}
```

Edit:  Using BigInteger class has the same issue.

```
Integer ncr(Integer n, Integer r) {
    if(n<r)
        return 0;
    BigInteger[] arr=new BigInteger[n+1];
    
    arr[0]=BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        for(int j=i; j>0; j--){
            if(arr[j]==null)
                arr[j]=BigInteger.ZERO;
            arr[j]=arr[j].add(arr[j-1]);
        }
    }
    
    return arr[r].intValue();
}
```

Edit-
The function should return BigInteger, not Integer.  See @leogtzr's code.

Comment: Try to change that to use long instead or try to implement it using the BigInteger class.

Comment: Thanks @leogtzr!  Using the BigInteger class has the same issue.

Comment: The result is: 
[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=C%28200%2C100%29)

```java
BigInteger ncr(final int n, final int r) {
    if (n < r) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }

    final BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
    
    arr[0] = BigInteger.ONE;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j].add(arr[j - 1]);
        }
    }

    return arr[r];
}
```

Comment: @leogtzr I believe your result is correct!  Your code is the solution.